# How to make textbox input go to a json dump website

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am new to javascript and html.

So for example:

`<input type='text'>`

So if the user put: "Hi, Hello, Welcome"
in the textbox would there be a script to put it in a json dump website or something(I'm new to json too so I dont know how to use it) ?
Please tell me if there is

UPDATE

For example if I was making a Cake Orderer website or something and this was my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Cake Order</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
            <h1> Enter Your Cake </h1>
            <input type="text">
        </center>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Would there be a way to update the website for the json 'dump' so I can click on the dump website link to see all the cake orders?

Comment: What is a json dump website?

Comment: can you put example json dump as output in your question ?

Comment: i dont know what a json dump website is but I have seen 'dumps' that are websites and not files

Comment: like i said i am not so good at json or html or javascript yet.

Comment: If you want one place where you could see all your orders, then you can create a page that returns the result of a select query on your DB where you will be storing your orders info.

Comment: i will try that